# DataStreamer addData method not work as expected in cluster

Tags: ignite

I have two notebook computers.Both of them installed windows7(64-bit),JDK 1.8.0_144(64-bit) and Ignite 2.1.0. I started a ignite node in first notebook's WindowsCMD with simple configuration xml like official example, then I run my code to start ignite node for adding lots of data in Eclipse on another notebook. Following is some pivotal part of my code:

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
tcpDiscoverySpi.setAckTimeout(15000);
tcpDiscoverySpi.setNetworkTimeout(60000);
TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509","192.168.1.105:47500..47509")); //two addresses of the notebook computers
tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg); //start ignite node
CacheConfiguration<Long, Map> cacheConf = new CacheConfiguration();
cacheConf.setName(CACHE_NAME).setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheConf.setBackups(0);
IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConf); //create cache

IgniteDataStreamer<Long,Map> ds = ignite.dataStreamer(CACHE_NAME);
ds.autoFlushFrequency(10000);
ds.perNodeBufferSize(1024);
ds.perNodeParallelOperations(8);
……  //some code to prepare for reading text data from local file
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){ // br is a BufferedReader instance
    ds.addData(count++, parseData(line, Constants.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, fields)); //parseData method return a Map instance
    if(count%100000==0){
        System.out.println(count+" loaded...");
    }
}
…… //other code
```

It run without error until ds.addData be called for several times, and following exception happened:

```
(err) Failed to execute compound future reducer: GridCompoundFuture [rdc=null, initFlag=1, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=[true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]]class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: DataStreamer request failed [node=b0a0b4f8-9f1e-49e9-8422-d9c0fe621398]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$Buffer.onResponse(DataStreamerImpl.java:1792)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$3.onMessage(DataStreamerImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1556)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1184)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1097)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to get deployment for request [sndId=d871b506-57ec-4c8e-ac79-d1c6f48786b3, req=DataStreamerRequest [reqId=1, cacheName=TestDataStreamer, ignoreDepOwnership=true, skipStore=false, keepBinary=false, depMode=SHARED, sampleClsName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$IsolatedUpdater, userVer=2, ldrParticipants=null, clsLdrId=1b30a534e51-d871b506-57ec-4c8e-ac79-d1c6f48786b3, forceLocDep=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=31, minorTopVer=1]]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.processRequest(DataStreamProcessor.java:273)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.access$000(DataStreamProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor$1.onMessage(DataStreamProcessor.java:89)
    ... 7 more
```

What's the reason?
What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Please share full logs from both nodes, it will help in investigation

Comment: I think I find the reason. There is a META-INF/ignite.xml legacy file in Eclipse and assign the userVersion value to "2", so the first node's version is "0" by default and is different from the one which is "2". It lead to the problem.